# Find web element by name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium.

I want to search for web element (button Edit) by it's name (Edit) but to avoid to use xpath as much as possible.

I have the following:

```
<td class="">
<a style="color:blue;" href="editdocumentation.php?documentId=143209&amp;
orderId=836837">**Edit**</a>
</td>
```

[image]

will it be correct to use:
Driver.findElement (By.cssSelector("a[name='Edit']")).click(); ?

If not, please give an advice how can I search by the name of the button (web object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an XPath to find an element:

1. Right click  of the mouse onto the web element.
2. Choose option Inspect.
3. On highlighted area right click of the mouse again.
4. Select Copy - Copy XPath.
5. Use copied XPath to find the web element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).